# How can I set the value in the input field when I make selection from the selector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-redux

When I make a selection, I want the input fields to get populated and also their value to be set to the corresponding value of selection. How should I do this?

[Output Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbJaH.png)

I couldn't share the full code snippet but this is the select box where I select the course name. On selecting the title, author & category field gets populated on the frontend. But when I looked at the value of the fields they do not get updated.

Full Code - https://codepen.io/ac5865/pen/dyqoRxR

```js
  ...
  <select
    name="title"
    validation="Please select title"
    invalid
    required
    onChange={(e) => {
      onInputChange(e);
    }}
  >
    <option>Choose Course</option>
    {users &&
      users.map((item) => (
        <option value={item.id} key={item.id}>
          {item.title}
        </option>
      ))}
  </select>
  <MDBInput
    value={select?.author}
    name="author"
    type="text"
    label="Author"
    onChange={(e) => {
      onInputChange(e);
    }}
    required
    validation="Please select title"
    invalid
  />
  <br />
  <MDBBtn type="submit">Enroll</MDBBtn>
  ...
```

The value gets populated on the front end but it does not get saved in the field

Comment: please post the complete code on stackblitz or codesandbox and provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this code snippets to understand how to implement onChange  with Select and Input field

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-cache-6krbdf?file=/src/App.js:0-654

In above code I am using same react state for both input field and select so when you Change value from select field it will reflect in input field.

Comment: You can improve this answer by explaining why and what you changed to make things working